# @Required not working in spring?

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

Am I using this in a wrong way, or @Required has no effect?

Here I annotated bean Non setter with @Required, but app starts normally and prints "null".

I would expect app to report an error and not start properly.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReqNotWorking {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReqNotWorking.class, args);
    }

    class Non{
        private String req;

        public String getReq() {
            return req;
        }

        @Required
        public void setReq(String req) {
            this.req = req;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Non non(){
        Non non = new Non();
        //non.setReq("error");
        return non;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(Non non){
        return args -> {

            System.out.println(non.getReq());

        };
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating the class `Non` via the `new` keyword so Spring has no way to apply its post-processors ([`RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html), specifically) and verify the value of the field.

As a side-note, the `@Required` annotation *probably* doesn't make sense in a Java-configured Spring application, where all beans are implicitly required, unless otherwise noted.

You didn't describe where the "`req`" string is supposed to come from, but if it's available at startup time, you could leverage the `@Value` mechanism:

```
@Component
static class Non {
    @Value("${req.value}")
    private String req;

    public String getReq() {
        return req;
    }
}
```

Comment: OK - so what is alternative for java config? I know about InitializingBean and asserting.

Comment: You didn't describe your use case, but one proposal added as an edit. If the given property is not available during startup, the app fails with an error.